# renaming C: after moving Windows 7 64-bit partitions to a SSD and keeping the old HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I bought a 500 GB (6-Gbit per second) SATA SSD to move my Windows 7 64-bit partition (and the 100 MB BCD partition) from a HDD. As that HDD has other partitions that I want to keep, the old HDD is not going to be removed.

Once new SSD was plugged into the motherboard and Win7 booted, I created a 100 MB primary partition on the SSD. Then I used **CloneZilla** ONLY to clone the BCD partition and the Windows 7 (**`C:`**) partition into the new SSD and changed the BIOS to boot from the new SSD disk.

The partitions are

```
  SSD:   [sdc1] BCD    [sdc2] \Windows
  HDD:   [sda1] BCD    [sda2] \Windows    [sda3] G:
```

But now the system boots from the new 100 MB BCD partition **`sdc1`** (that is fine) but Windows 7 is started from the old HDD partition **`sda2`**, not from the cloned SDD one **`sdc2`**. In fact, the new Windows partition (**`sdc2`**) is labeled as **`H:`**

I did not manage to rename the Windows **`C:`** disk partition.

I guess the BCD partition keeps the UUID (or similar) of the partition which Windows boots from, but I'm not familiar with it.

How can I make Windows 7 to boot from **`sdc2`**?
Is it just a Windows relabelling disk issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The UUIDs of the old partitions are still in the Windows registry.

Comment: A 6 GB SSD isn’t large enough to install Windows.  So what size is it?

Comment: No, it is not a 6 Gbyte SSD. It's a 500 GB with a 6 Gigabit per second SATA interface.

Comment: @Ramhound  - Question text corrected

Comment: You really don't need to indicate more than its a SATA III device, the specifications of SATA III, should be presumed to be known.